# The meaning of 'take over' in this sentence

Tags: meaning, slang, phrasal-verbs, internet

I've recently watched a youtube video where a person mentioned a phrase *'It's pretty much **taken over** my Instragram'*. I think she meant *'The pictures are taken over.'* I tried to find out all of the meanings of the phrasal verb but I didn't find the one that would suit the context.
Could anyone explain it to me? :-) I wondered if it might be a slang.

Comment: "It's" is an abbreviation of "It has" in this context. So it would presumably mean "The pictures *have* taken over.'  This means that they dominate her Instagram.

Comment: "Taken over" can be roughly translated as "taken control of".

Answer (score 1):

There are many definitions of the transitive verb "take over". But the relevant ones in this context are to take possession of, to dominate, or to take control of. These definitions make sense when you understand the first word in your example sentence to mean "It has" rather than "It is."

> It has pretty much taken over my Instagram.

Or more simply:

> It has taken over my Instagram.

Thus, whatever "it" is has dominated this person's social media news feed.

For reference (from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+over)):

- **take over**

  1. To assume control, management, or responsibility: I'm taking over while the supervisor is on vacation.
  2. To assume the control or management of or the responsibility for: She took over the job after he left.
  3. To become dominant: Our defense took over in the second half of the game.
  4. To do (an action or a play in a game) again when the first performance has been discounted or is under dispute.